# Open different forms on different button click in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

A noob query I have, is there any way to use a single command to open different forms on different button click events. I have 24 buttons in one form and will use these buttons to open 24 different forms.

So instead of doing it for 24 times as:

```
 Private Sub BtnCh1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCh1.Click
    FormCh1.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub BtnCh2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCh2.Click
    FormCh2.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub BtnCh3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCh3.Click
    FormCh3.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub BtnCh4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCh4.Click
    FormCh4.Show()
End Sub
```

Can it be done with a single command?

Comment: Add all the forms in a `List(Of Form)`, add the index in each of the button's `Tag` property, set all the button with the same event and call `list(CType(sender,Button).Tag).Show()`

Comment: @ Keith: How do I add the forms in `List(Of Form)`?

Comment: I'll add it in an answer to make things readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form's load event add the forms in a `List(Of Form)`

```
Private list As List(Of Form)
Private Sub Me_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    list = New List(Of Form)
    list.Add(New Form1())
    '
    '
    '
    list.Add(New Form24())
End Sub
```

Set your button's `Tag` property with the form's index and set them all to use the same click event:

```
Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
    list(CType(sender, Button).Tag).Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Attach all the handlers to your method and then branch behaviour based on the Select Case:

```
Private Sub Button_Click_Handler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button66.Click, Button67.Click, Button68.Click

    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    Select Case btn.Name
        Case Button66.Name
            Dim f1 As New Form1
            f1.Show()
        Case Button67.Name
            Dim f2 As New Form2
            f2.Show()
        Case Button68.Name
            Dim f3 As New Form3
            f3.Show()
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Why compare against name when you could compare against reference?

Comment: No good reason. I expect they'd both work well, unless there is a good reason not to compare against name.

Comment: Because reference comparison is faster than string comparison. Though I thought you could compare by reference by using `Case Is ...`, however after actually testing it I found out that that did not work. If it would've been possible to do so you wouldn't have had to type as much text. -- However after running an actual test on reference vs string comparison, I learned that comparing strings in `Select Case` is a rather big bottleneck. See: http://ideone.com/BCMEIR

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the analysis! I don't pay too much attention to performance when the process is not going to be iterative.

Comment: Well I'm kinda fixated on always getting as good performance as possible, don't really know why... Although I relax it more when, as you say, the process is not iterative. ;)